# Why mvn compile lifecycle phase is not compiling only changed java files?

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a Java project which is using **JDK 1.8** and **Maven 3.9** build tool.

Here is the **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprojectcodestyle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, when I executed `mvn compile` phase on the project. I see that it compiled 5 files. That's okay.

Now I changed only one file and executed the `mvn compile` phase again. It compiled the 5 files again.

Why this happened? Is it possible to tell maven to compile only changed files?

Comment: Short answer, no and it shouldn't. Maven is a build tool and designed to compile everything on the scope of a project. Here is an example why it shouldn't: Say you have A and B classes. A uses a method on B called `xMethod` you then rename B xMethod to yMethod. How will your A class know that a change was made? It should fail in the compilation process because a reference was broken.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Bad. The another build system Gradle compile only changed files.

Comment: What you are talking about in Gradle is called Compile Avoidance and it is not that it only compiles changed files it compiles everything that is needed to be compiled, in the example given for instance it would still compile both A and B. Here https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance

Comment: First I strongly recommend to use the most recent version of the maven-compiler-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) because version 3.1 is more than a decade old. Second you should only use `<maven.compiler.source>..</maven.compiler.source>` and `<maven.compiler.target>..</maven.compiler.target` if building with JDK8 or less... for JDK9+ you should use only `<maven.compiler.release>..</maven.compiler.release>` and only define in the properties and no supplemental configuration in the plugin itself. The `<compilerVersion>..</compilerVersion>` only makes sense if you defined forking

Comment: This is also true for maven-surefire-plugin... check the linked page https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<useIncrementalCompilation>` feature from `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Read the Maven docs for [`useIncrementalCompilation`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useIncrementalCompilation).

---

Just add the below line in the `maven-compiler-plugin` to turn off the incremental compilation.

```
<useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
```

This will make sure that changed files are only picked up for compilation.

Updated **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprojectcodestyle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Note:** Try to use the latest version for maven plugins. Although `<useIncrementalCompilation>` feature works from `maven-compiler-plugin` version **3.1** onwards.

Comment: Upgrade the verisons you are using... those things are ancient old...

Comment: @khmarbaise Updated my answer.